# What is the difference between a Portlet label and a Portlet page (Websphere Portal Server 6.1)

Tags: portlet, websphere-portal

What is the difference between a portlet label and a portlet page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following references:

- [Portlet Label](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc_v615/admin/mp_create_labels.html)
- [Portlet Page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc_v615/admin/h_mp_create_pages.html)